# Display delayed with Flexslider 2

Tags: jquery, flexslider, delayed-execution

I'm working on my own portfolio (which is not complete now), and i'm having issues with Flexslider 2 (by [Woothemes](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/)).

See here : http://www.gaelle-fernandez.fr/Folio2012/#Works
If you click on a work (any image), a slickbox will open, with a slider and a description.
As you can see, the slider does not show the images at first opening, you have to wait 10seconds at least. It's embarassing, because I want to show my works without any delay...

here is my code of **index.php**

```
<head>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/flexslider.css" media="screen"/>
   <script src="Js/jquery.flexslider.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
         $(window).load(function() {
             $('.flexslider').flexslider({
               animation: "slide",
               controlNav: true,
               animationLoop: true,
               slideshow: false,
             });
          }); 
   </script>  
    <div id="header">
        <!-- my header content -->
    </div>
    <ol id="main" class="curtains">
        <li id="Works" class="cover">
            <h2 style="padding-left:615px;">Derniers Travaux</h2>
            <div id="slickbox">
               <div id="sliderContent">
                   <div class="flexslider">
                        <ul class="slides">
                            <li>
                                <img src="Img/creas/crea.png" />
                            </li>
                            <!-- other images -->
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h1>TITLE </h1>
                <p>Big Description Bacon Ipsum.</p>
                <div id="btn-close"><b>X</b></div>
             </div>
             <div id="worksContent">
                 <ul id="themes"> Themes LI</ul>
                 <ul id="creations" class="step">
                     <li class="step frmwk">
                          <div class="item">
                              <a href="#">
                                  <img src="Img/creas/crea.png" alt="title" title="" width="226" height="147"/>
                              </a>
                              <div class="caption">
                                 <h3>Framework Work</h3>
                                 <p>Little description</p>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                      </li>
<!-- Other content -->
</body>
```

(or you can see it with firebug)

I know my code is ruining your eyes, but for the moment it is more a draft than a real website.

So, could you help me to know **why there is a delay for the display of my images within the slider**, please?

**Thanks by advance for your time!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same annoying issue.

Adding this

```
style="display: list-item"
```

to the first list (li) child within `.slides` will do the trick.

Comment: thanks @ReeceAlexander, because i did a magic trick : i display a loader, so even if flexslider does not show my images, the visitor can see there is something happening. But, now, i'll try your fixes! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try setting all slides to `display:none` like this

```css
#sliderContent .slides li {
    display: none;
}
```

That fixed it for me. I think FlexSlider wants all slides to be hidden to begin with. The delay you see is because it displays the last slide, but internally steps trough all slides, running their animations and everything, but you just don't see it because the last one has higher z-index and is visible.